# ASP.NET MVC - JQuery ActionLink and Ajax call on div click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using an ActionLink to call a the method below

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "addLine",Nothing,New With {.id = "addItem"})

$("#addItem").click(function () {
        alert(this.href);
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#editorrows").append(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

It works fine.
I want to replicate the same behavior when a user clicks on a DIV. I've tried a couple of things but they don't seem to work, I'm guessing because the link makes a get call to the URL?

Comment: i don't understand the quesiton.  if it works fine, what's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work when I try the div ID.
As I said in the original post, I think it's because the action link makes a GET request or something while clicking on the div wouldn't behave like that.

Comment: Obviously it won't work with the div, because div doesn't have "this.href" defined.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on a `div` because you have this in your code:

```
 url: this.href
```

The `div` probably does not have an `href` attribute.
Try to specify the URL explicitly in the JavaScript code.

```
 url: '/controller/addLine?id="addItem"'
```

However, you will loose the dynamic URL generation based on the routes.
Alternatively, store the URL in an attribute of the `div` and read it from the JavaScript:

```
<div data-action-url="@Url.Action("addLine", Nothing, New With { .id = "addItem" })"></div>
```

In the JavaScript:

```
  url: $(this).data("action-url")
```